# There is a problem when i am getting index of subview

Tags: iphone, uiview, xib

There is a problem when i am getting index of subview.

```
int index = [[YourUIView subviews] indexOfObject:YourUIButton];
```

Some UITextField are created with xib file. When i printed its value i get unreal index.
 @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *distanceTextField; for example: index is equal to 2147483647

But when i add object programmatically i get real index. index is equal to 12. Why ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each time you perform a search for some index (or range) with framework methods check its result against `NSNotFound` constant. On your platform NSNotFound is happened to be 2147483647. That solves the mystery of unreal index.

```
int index = [parentView.subviews indexOfObject:importantButton];
if (index != NSNotFound) {
  // found it
} else {
  // no luck
}
```

As for question why your view is not found - check if every outlet actually points to some view at the moment you perform this search.

**Update**

You can check if outlet is set with debugger or by logging it

```
    NSLog(@"myView - %@", myView);
```

Comment: oh no, UITextField *distancetextField; @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *distanceTextField; - mispelled;  hoha - thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, the index is [`NSNotFound`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html), which is the same as `NSIntegerMax` or 2147483647, telling you that the object's index wasn't found.

Try manually setting the index of the object in Interface Builder and searching on that.